# How to copy resources in a gradle javafx project

Tags: gradle, javafx

I have a Javafx project with Gradle. Gradle uses the standard "java" and "application" plugins.

I would like to have a project structure like this.

```
src
...main
.......java
...........myApp
................module1
.......................module1.fxml
.......................modele1Controller.java
.......................module1YY.java
```

My problem is that module1.fxml is never copied to the output directory.

I tried to make a Gradle task like:

```
task('fxCopy',type:Copy) {
    from(file('srcDir'))
    into(buildDir)
    include('**/*.fxml')
}
processResources.finalizedBy fxCopy
```

I hoped that it would copy module1.fxml to the correct location,, but no...

Gradle is new to me,, can anyone help me with a Gradle task to do the work????

/regards
/lg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line (and you do not need the `fxCopy` task)

`sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir 'src/main/java'`

Comment: Not working for  me.  No .fxml files in the output directory. Am I missing something else?

Comment: My mistake. Works nicely. Tanks.